# Geo Map with pinning location

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-visualization, leaflet, geocoding

I am showing world map on dashboard where few locations needs to shown as highlighted. I need to highlight few locations on map based on airport code. For example, IAD is airport code for Dallas, So if a data-center having IAD in its name then Dallas will be highlighted on Map.
Till yet, I tried **leaflet.js** an open source geo map library. but it requires coordinates to pin a location. I want something like google map (can't use google API as paid tool) where you may pin a location by its name.

If somebody could suggest a library or a heads-up towards how to achieve it, It would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong in question which attracted downvotes ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Leaflet, you will **need** lat-lng coordinates no matter what.

If you only have placenames, then you'll have to run a geocoding query to convert the addesss/placename into lat-lng coordinates. You might want to start your search in the [list of geocoding plugins for Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding).